# Regex Variable Size HexString Parsing

Tags: regex

I am not familiar with Regex and I need to parse a spec using Regex.

I need to get the KEK, Key and Wrap hex values into a string/hex array but the hex string lengths can be variadic and have spaces. Please see an example below

```
   The second example wraps 7 octets of key data with a 192-bit KEK.
      KEK   :  5840df6e29b02af1 ab493b705bf16ea1 ae8338f4dcc176a8
      Key   :  466f7250617369
      Wrap  :  afbeb0f07dfbf541 9200f2ccb50bb24f
```

The explanation tells the length of the key which might be used; example "7 octets of key data"

The other problem is that online regex tools and online python interpreters to run python regex lib (re) behaves different so I can not be sure about the regex expression.

I tried to get a line using

```
(\w+)\s+:\s+([A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d]([A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d])*)
```

but it parse a line until space in hex string.

Any recommendation on that

Comment: You can repeat it 0 or more times with a group `(\w+)\s+:\s+([A-Fa-f\d]+(?: [A-Fa-f\d]+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/Vzxj5I/1 Of repeat parts of 2 chars `(\w+)\s+:\s+((?:[A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d])+(?: (?:[A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d])+)*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/UTxA8l/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you are matching 2 chars and then optionally repeat per 2 chars. But you are repeating a capture group without matching spaces.

You can reuse that same mechanism optionally repeating per 2 chars with 1 or more whitespace chars prepended in a non capture group, and capture that whole repetition in an outer capture group.

```
(\w+)\s+:\s+((?:[A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d])+(?:\s+(?:[A-Fa-f\d][A-Fa-f\d])+)*)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrfKQg/1)

The same mechanism as the above pattern to repeat 1 or more characters instead of per 2 characters:

```
(\w+)\s+:\s+([A-Fa-f\d]+(?:\s+[A-Fa-f\d]+)*)\b
```

- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `\s+:\s+` match `:` between 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[A-Fa-f\d]+` Match 1+ times any of the ranges
  - `(?:\s+[A-Fa-f\d]+)*` Match 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ times any of the ranges
- `)` Close **group 2**
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MQEaB0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much The fourth bird, it definitely parses the hex mentioned above.
But I have noticed that there are some irregular lines like below

```
   The first example wraps 20 octets of key data with a 192-bit KEK.

      KEK   :  5840df6e29b02af1 ab493b705bf16ea1 ae8338f4dcc176a8

      Key   :  c37b7e6492584340 bed1220780894115 5068f738

      Wrap  :  138bdeaa9b8fa7fc 61f97742e72248ee 5ae6ae5360d1ae6a
            :  5f54f373fa543b6a
```

"Wrap" line is two lines and there is one more colon(:) symbol, I don't know is there anything to do here.